# Resend Webhook Notification on Docusign

Tags: webhooks, docusignapi

Is it possible to request from the API to resend a webhook?

From here i can see this is possible from the Admin Panel
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/

> When a webhook request fails, the Failures screen also enables you to
>   resend the notification. This can be very helpful when debugging your
>   listener software.

I want to do the same but from the API.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ConnectEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/) Api's.

Specifically the following api's

- [retryForEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/retryForEnvelope/)

  > Republishes Connect information for the specified envelope.
- [retryForEnvelopes](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/retryForEnvelopes/)

  > Republishes Connect information for the specified set of envelopes. The primary use is to republish Connect post failures by including envelope IDs for the envelopes that failed to post in the request. The list of envelope IDs that failed to post correctly can be retrieved by calling to [ML:GetConnectLog] retrieve the failure log.

Comment: Hi @CodingDawg 
Thanks for your response, that endpoint looks good. My question now is that i set my Connect config as a Per-envelope Connect Configuration using the `eventNotification` on the create endpoint for evenlope.

When i return a 400 or 500 from the webhook i see the envelope is not added to the failure list. Something i am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: When creating the envelope, are you setting the [requireAcknowledgment](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/eventNotification) property in your eventNotification object?

Comment: Ohh, i am sending it as a boolean, let me try with a String. Checking, Thanks!

Comment: No luck with boolean or string type of `requireAcknowledgment`.
Anything more that we need to setup the failure queue?

Comment: Hi @CodingDawn, don't worry i have a typo error in that property...
Sorry, thanks for your help!

Comment: @CodingDawn
One last question, is it possible to resend a webhook before we set the `requireAcknowledgment` property to an specific envelope?

Thanks